# Equivalent of std::vector in Java?

Tags: java

What would be the closest thing to a std::vector in Java? By this I mean, a class which can take in T into its constructor and then pushBack, popBack() and that is stored in continuous memory (not linked list).

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need something that is stored in continuous memory yet has a Push and Pop operation just like a stack?

Comment: @ferrari fan: I presume he's just mentioning those since C++'s vector class has similar methods.

Comment: @Fast He probably means contiguous :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
Everything's stored in array ("contiguous memory") internally, although operation names are a bit different.

[A bit more about list implementations in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)
[And about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

**edit**
**Helper Method** also mentioned useful class in his answer (although not exactly equivalent to C++ Vector).

Comment: Can't a Java Vector be used instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 9):

That would probably be [ArrayDeque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), if you need Stack functionality.

Do not use the [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class as other here suggest.

Comment: Good call, though `ArrayList` would still be a closer match because it supports indexed element access like the C++ `vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Is ArrayList what you're looking for? 
`ArrayList l = new ArrayList<String>();` 
So you can have a list of anything (defined between the <>).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [`ArrayDeque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) which supports push/pop style access from both ends of the list efficiently.

**Avoid** `Stack` and `Vector` - these are synchronized, which implies generally pointless overhead.

`ArrayList` is also fine; however, you'd need to implement your own (trivial) pop method since it is not provided by the class itself.  `ArrayList` does permit indexed access, which `ArrayDeque` lacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`ArrayDeque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), it doesn't support random access but support `Deque` (double ended queue) methods

Answer (score 0):

Java has Stack which supports push and pop. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about simply the Vector class?

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: `Vector` is pretty much deprecated, use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I stand corrected. It seems this point has been discussed here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

What you need is exactly an `java.util.ArrayList<T>` You can check the documentation in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Basically is a List implemented with an Array where the references live in a continuous chunk of memory.

I recommend to use in combination with a interface variable like this: `List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();`
so if you decide, you can change the implementation to `java.util.LinkedList<T>` or another one.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is the LinkedList

```
vector (c++)   <===========> linkedlist(java) 
v.front()      <===========> l.peekFirst() 
v.back()       <===========> l.peekLast()  
v.push_back(x) <===========> l.add(x) 
v.pop_back()   <===========> l.pollLast()
```

Comment: Aren't these completely different data types?

Comment: No. Linked list is when each element contains a pointer to the next and the previous element, these elements aren't store continuously in memory. Elements in vector ARE actually stored continuously, one after the other in memory, much like an array.

Comment: I believe this one is the best. The vector often declared empty, so contiguous allocation in memory doesn't matter if you don't need fast indexed access and LinkedList has all the equivalent methods available, as well as indexed access too(yes, not so fast). ArrayDeck doesn't have indexed access at all.

Comment: No, LinkedList is the equivalent of std::list. The expectation of std::vector is that accessing by index is O(1) and LinkedList (and std::list) is O(n). Even if all you need is a place to store items and iterate over them, an array will take up less memory (no need for back/forward pointers) and have better cache performance. LinkedList is better if you are frequently adding and removing from the middle (O(1)), as an array would copy (O(n)). But OP specifically said NOT a linked list.