# Push_back and pop_back in java

Tags: java, c++, arraylist, vector, stl

I am coming from a C++ background. I use vector push_back and pop_back methods to push and pop out elements from the vector. I know arraylist is sort of equivalent to vector, but I don'f find equivalent methods to push_back and pop_back in arraylist API. The closet I could find is LinkedList. Am I missing something or is there any other equivalent to vector in C++?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you want a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Comment: maybe `add()` and `remove()`? Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: C++ vector givesadditional functionality of accessing elements randomly (Since vector is internally an array). Stack does not allow such random access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of std::vector in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731067/equivalent-of-stdvector-in-java)

Answer (score 16):

Use **`add()`** from [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to **`push_back`**.

For **`pop_back`** you have to play around a bit more with indexes and **`remove()`**.

Let's look at this example:

```
// push_back equivalent
ArrayList<int> a = new ArrayList<int>();
a.add(2);             // Add element to the ArrayList.
a.add(4);

// pop_back equivalent.
a.remove(a.size()-1); // Remove the last element from the ArrayList.
```

Comment: The 'pop_back' equivalent can be more direct: "a.remove(a.size() - 1);".  There's no need to 'get' it first.

Comment: Noted. Thanks@DaveDoknjas !

Comment: Whoops. Legacy comment. Thanks @NathanOliver

Answer (score 3):

Use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for dynamically add and remove element.

**For `push_back()` use `.add()`**

[add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) method to add elements in the list

```
List<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
arrlist.add(10);
```

**For `pop_back()` use `.remove()`**

[remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) used for removing the element at the specified position in this list. So,
pass last index in  method to delete last element

```
arrlist.remove(arrlist.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [`LinkedList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) data structure

Adding at the end by: [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E))

removing at the end by using: [`pollLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pollLast())

**Example:**

```
package test;

import java.util.*;  
public class test{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

    LinkedList<String> al=new LinkedList<String>();  
    al.add("element1");  
    al.add("element2");  
    al.add("element3");  

    Iterator<String> itr=al.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.print(itr.next()+" ");  
    } 

    System.out.println(" ");

    al.add("element4");  

    itr=al.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.print(itr.next()+ " "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(" ");

    //pop_back
    al.pollLast();

    itr=al.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.print(itr.next()+" ");  
      }  
    }  
}
```

**result:**

```
element1 element2 element3  
element1 element2 element3 element4  
element1 element2 element3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add()` for `push_back()` and `remove()` for `pop_back()`.

```
ArrayList<data_type> data = new ArrayList<data_type>();
data.add(value1);
data.add(value2);
data.remove(data.size() - 1);
```

P.S : `arraylist` is a container not API.